# Pass environment variable values inside Dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I am using environment variables under my ECS task def which pull values. The variable name is say encryptor.password I have this also declared in my Dockerfile as ENV variable with some dummy value but at the same time is called at a later entrypoint section something like below :-

```html
ARG pwd
ENV encryptor.password $pwd
# Run the app.jar using the recommended flags per
# https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/#_containerize_it
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dhttp.proxyHost=***",\
"-Dhttps.proxyHost=***","-Dhttp.proxyPort=***",\
"-Dhttps.proxyPort=***","-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true",\
"-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=***|/var/run/docker.sock|***|***|***",\
"-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dencryptor.password=${encryptor.password}","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev",\
"-jar","/app/app.jar"]
```

My understanding is that -Dencryptor.password=${encryptor.password} should actually be replaced by the value that is coming to this dockerfile for the ENV variable encryptor.password from the taskdef when the container starts, but looks like the entrypoint is not picking that value. Am i missing something. How to get Dockerfile to get that value?

Comment: how are you launching your container ?   if you are using a docker-compose.yaml file it can pass env vars into the container ... take note there is a distinction between compiling the Dockerfile to synthesize an image and the launch of the image using docker-compose.yaml ... aws can be used along with a docker-compose.yaml

Comment: The container is just being launched in aws ECS using ECS default functionality. So i run a build and deploy that updates the taskdef with a new revision that has the new image and updates the service in the ECS cluster which forces a new task (docker container) to start up in the EC2 there, but possibly fails when the entrypoint executes as its unable to get the actual value for encryptor.password, as it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that you need to firstly use shell form of ENTRYPOINT so either have an entrypoint.sh script where you define your commands and arguments and then execute in shell form from ENTRYPOINT or else pass everything as :-

```html
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java ........."]
```

At the same time make sure the variables parsed in ENTRYPOINT for shell do not use dots. Dots are not valid shell identifiers and very commonly overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend to store your environment variable in the task definition. There is some advantage over Dockerfile.

1. More secure than Docker ENV
2. Ability to override at run time
3. Zero chances of being missed like it seems env is missed during build time in your case
4. Available across multiple services

You can define ENV is task definition under the container section.

[image]

Comment: Yeah its in the task def, but i also want to access it in the docker entrypoint script. The variable name in task def is encryptor.password with some value. Also in the entrypoint of you see its encryptor.password=${encryptor.password}. How do i get to override ${encryptor.password} as the actual value in the entrypoint

Comment: If you set the env in task definition it will pick the new value in entry point t0o. Just set this in task definition it will override encryptor.password

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
ARG pwd
```

means that you need to supply a value during build time: add --build-arg to `docker build`.

If you want the value to be supplied to the container when you launch it, then you need to remove the ARG line and the `$pwd` from the declaration of the ENV. `docker run' accepts the option`--env` where you can supply your values.